# Multiple AJAX Requests When Clicking 'View Leads' Button - How to Send Only One Request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

When clicking the "View Leads" button on my web app, it sends multiple AJAX requests with the same data instead of just one. I'm using jQuery, and I've tried using a flag to prevent simultaneous requests, but the problem persists. How can I fix this to ensure only one AJAX request is sent per click? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

````
<script>  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Flag to track if an AJAX request is in progress
    let isRequestInProgress = false;

    // Function to handle the click event on the "View Leads" button
    function handleViewLeadsClick(carId) {
      // Check if an AJAX request is already in progress
      if (isRequestInProgress) {
        return;
      }

      // Set the flag to true to indicate that an AJAX request is in progress
      isRequestInProgress = true;

      // Make an AJAX request to the server
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://mywebsite.ca/ajax2.php",
        data: { carId: carId },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
          // Reset the flag to false after the AJAX request is completed
          isRequestInProgress = false;

          // Check if the response contains data
          if (response && response.data) {
            // Create an HTML table to display the data
            let tableHtml = '<table id="leads-table" class="display nowrap" style="width: 100%"><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Mobile</th><th>Time</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

            // Loop through the data and add rows to the table
            response.data.forEach(function(item) {
              tableHtml += '<tr><td>' + item.id + '</td><td>' + item.mobile + '</td><td>' + item.time + '</td><td>' + item.status + '</td></tr>';
            });

            // Close the table body and table tag
            tableHtml += '</tbody></table>';

            // Display the table using SweetAlert2 with custom width
            Swal.fire({
              title: 'Leads Data',
              html: tableHtml,
              confirmButtonText: 'Close',
              customClass: {
                // Add a custom CSS class to control the width of the modal
                container: 'custom-sweetalert2-container'
              },
              // Adjust the width for different screen sizes
              width: '90%', // Set the initial width of the modal
              responsive: true, // Allow responsiveness for mobile devices
              // Optional breakpoint settings for responsiveness
              breakpoints: {
                768: { // Set breakpoint for screens smaller than 768px (e.g., mobile devices)
                  width: '95%' // Adjust width for mobile devices
                }
              }
            });

            // Initialize DataTable on the created table
            $('#leads-table').DataTable({
              scrollX: true,
              scrollCollapse: true,
              autoWidth: false
            });
          }
        },
        error: function() {
          // Reset the flag to false after the AJAX request is completed
          isRequestInProgress = false;

          // Handle the error if the AJAX request fails
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Oops...',
            text: 'Something went wrong while fetching data!',
            confirmButtonText: 'Close'
          });
        }
      });
    }

    // Attach the click event handler using event delegation to the parent element
    $(document).on('click', '.view-leads-btn', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default anchor click behavior
      const carId = $(this).data('carid'); // Get the data-carid attribute value
      handleViewLeadsClick(carId); // Call the function to handle the click event
    });
  });
</script>```

View Leads Button repeats multiple time on same page.


```<span class="vehica-panel-card__action">
                <a href="#" class="view-leads-btn" data-carid="<?php echo $vehicaCar->getId(); ?>">
                    <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                    <?php echo "View Leads"; ?>
                </a>
            </span>```




Attempted to prevent multiple AJAX requests using the isRequestInProgress flag. Expected one AJAX request per click on the "View Leads" button, but multiple requests are still being sent.
````

Comment: you are using event delegation but you never refer to `e.target` which is the element that was clicked.

Comment: Simple solution would be to disable the button before the ajax call and enable when you get something in return from the ajax call using jquery, $('#buttonID').prop('disabled', true/false)